# Copying someone in email

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, email

I have often seen people writing a line like this in emails:

> I have copied xyz on this email.

This reads funny to me. I always thought it should be "I have copied this email to xyz". That makes more sense to me.

Is the first usage correct? How did it come into being?

Comment: Related: [Where did CC: come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28105)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary definition 1c of the verb *copy* includes:

> to provide (someone) with copies of correspondence, etc., on a
>   particular subject for information. (Common in office use.)

The entry has this supporting citation from a novel published in 1983:

> LaSalle pushed a file jacket across the table, and Harper flipped
>   through the pages.‥ ‘You'll copy me on all this?’ said Harper.

So the answers to your question are that *copy* followed by a human direct object is established and recognised and that it has been around for almost 30 years, and possibly longer.